# Regarding soap ui

Tags: soap

**While Quering a account from one Salesforce Organization to another salesforce Organization using Soap Ui "Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService"**

This the Request Body in Soap Ui

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <urn:SessionHeader>
    <urn:sessionId>--------------------</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:query>
         <urn:queryString>select Name from account</urn:queryString>
      </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**This is the Response Body is Returning in Soap Ui**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode>
         <faultstring>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService</sf:exceptionMessage>
            </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**How to Rectify this Issue,Please Anyone Guide Me For Help**

Answer (score 1):

What URL are you sending the request to from SOAP UI?

It seems likely that you are sending it to https://**login.salesforce.com**/services/Soap/u/36.0

If that is the case, you need to change it to the pod/instance URL that is returned from a call to the login method. It will be something like:

```
https://na5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/36.0
```

Note the na5 subdomain. This indicates the instance were your session will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the serverUrl returned from the login step call which resembles something as below :

`<serverUrl>https://instance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0/00Dj0000000I5OP/0DF15000000Pblx</serverUrl>`

Put this serverUrl as the endpoint of your Request as displayed in image below

[image: instance.salesforce.com/services/ highlight]